# Is the 'toString' method of Java Wrapper classes overloaded or is it an abstract method that has different definitions in different classes?

Tags: java, class, wrapper, overloading

In the below Program I am trying to convert Numbers into strings using the static 'toString' method of the Wrapper classes.

```
class NumberToStringConversion
{
  public NumberToStringConversion()
 {
  String I=Integer.toSring(i);
  String F=Float.toString(f);
  String D=Double.toString(d);
  String L=Long.toString(l);
 }
}
```

Here, Integer, Float, Double and Long are Wrapper classes that box respective Primitive datatypes. It looks like the `toString` method is present in all the aforementioned wrapper classes. Does that mean the `toString` method is overloaded? or is it an `abstract` method that has different definitions in different classes?

Comment: No. They're different methods on different classes, but happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 5):

The `toString()` methods you're calling are static methods. Inheritance doesn't apply to static methods. Each of the wrapper classes has both static and non-static `toString()` methods. The static ones are unrelated to each other. The non-static ones override `Object.toString()`.

`Integer`, for example, has three `toString()` methods:

```
String toString();  // overrides Object.toString()
static String toString(int i);
static String toString(int i, int radix);
```

Comment: Thank you John. I understand that the static methods are called using the class name 'Integer.toString' and can be used even if the class is never instantiated and has no objects created.  So, is it just for the sake of convenience that all these methods have the same name?

Comment: Yes, it's for consistency.